# Looking for the title of a book where the ruling women have psychic powers

Tags: story-identification, psychic, mind-control

This book was published in the 70's or 80's.  The women had psychic powers but were bonded to their husbands who they could not disobey.  The heroine of the book is bonded to a man (who is the bastard son of one of the rulers) against her will but her unique combination of powers allow her to break free of his control. They then compete in a sort of tournament in order to free the exploited underclass of their world.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: That triggers a vague memory. Something by Sharon Green, perhaps?